# How to use Stylelint to prevent use of "max-width" in media queries

Tags: stylelint

I'd like to warn/error when using `max-width` in media queries and encourage a mobile-first approach with `min-width`.

Can I warn/error on...

```
@media (max-width: 50em) {
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

But allow...

```
@media (min-width: 50em) {
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

Comment: I couldn't come up with any that would allow this, so I've just proposed two new rules that would allow this, `media-feature-blacklist` & `media-feature-whitelist`, see https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/issues/1722. If/once accepted an answer can be posted using the new rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `media-feature-name-disallowed-list` and `media-feature-name-allowed-list` rules can now be used in the latest stylelint:

```
"media-feature-name-disallowed-list": [
  "^max-width",
    {
      "message": "Use min-width for a mobile-first approach (media-feature-name-disallowed-list)",
    },
  ],
},
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this, @netweb! Really appreciate the work all of you put into Stylelint.

Answer (score 2):

You should now use `media-feature-name-disallowed-list` (https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/media-feature-name-disallowed-list)

Answer (score 1):

I got the error "media-feature-name-no-unknown" for using max-width in a selector.

To allow the usage in my .stylelintrc.json:

```json
    "media-feature-name-no-unknown": [
      {
        "ignoreMediaFeatureNames": [
          "max-width"
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Example valid usage (styled-components):

```
const StyledSectionDrawer = styled.div`
  @media screen and (max-width: ${(props) => props.breakpoint}px) {
    margin-top: ${standardNavHeight}px;
  }
  @media screen and (min-width: ${(props) => props.breakpoint}px) {
    margin-top: ${(props) => (props.scrolled ? standardNavHeight : props.navHeight)}px;
  }
`;
```

via https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/list/media-feature-name-no-unknown/